# OnResume to only happen when activity is accessed the second time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, onresume

I am trying to write code for my android application for things to happen when the activity is Resumed. Although I only want this stuff to happen when the activity is re-visited for the second time and not the first time.

So I want the user to do what they need in the `onCreate` method in their first visit to the activity and then when they go back to the activity then the `onResume` code happens.

Should I be using a different method or how can I achieve what I am looking to do?

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    RunningStatus = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("RunningStatus", false);

    if (isS1Pressed) {
        if (isPressed) {
            if (RunningStatus = false) {
                pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I don't mean second time I mean every time after. Basically I have a production line and my app determines whether it is ahead or behind. So when the user enters this activity then the can perform the calculation. We have a pause button where the user can pause the line if the production line has been stopped in real life. Although I would like that the user can then go out of that specific production line and do calculations on other lines too. Although at the minute once I leave the activity I lose all its state.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to happen only for the second time or any subsequent times? Also, is it meant to happen only when you return from a certain activity, or every time the activity is "seen" on screen?

Comment: Why dont you put just in onResume(), which is called after onCreate()

Comment: Reading through your question it seems you did not understand well the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: By "first visit" you mean first visit ever, or first visit since the app is open ? I mean if I open the app, go to your activity, then close (totally close, not only pressing home button), then re-open the app and go to your activity, This will be count as the second time ?

Comment: By "when they go back" and "second time" do you mean that user is in your activity, he open a new activity (by pressing a button for example) and then go back to the first activity (by pressing back for example) ? In this case look for `OnActivityResult()`

Comment: I don't mean second time I mean every time after. Basically I have a production line and my app determines whether it is ahead or behind. So when the user enters this activity then the can perform the calculation. We have a pause button where the user can pause the line if the production line has been stopped in real life. Although I would like that the user can then go out of that specific production line and do calculations on other lines too. Although at the minute once I leave the activity I lose all its state.

Comment: @vincrichaud for onActivityResult() would I put the code that I want to run when the activity is re-vistited in there?

Comment: I think your knowledge on activity lifecycle and saving instance state is wanting. You might also look into `startActivityForResult` in your case. Please check here for the understanding of the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: @ReazMurshed so do I put the code that I have onResume() inside startActivityForResult?

Comment: Did you read the documentation properly? Is it really necessary to put the code in the `onResume` function when you come back to the activity for the second time? And yes, I think you should start activities from your parent activity using `startActivityForResult` and place the code into `onActivityResult` which you have placed inside `onResume`. However, I do not know the exact implementation yet. So please figure out the best implementation what suits you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean flag. in `onResume` e.g.

```
if (secondVisit) {
  ...
} else secondVisit = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some stuff for very specific time (only 2nd, not 1st or 3rd, 4th,...), I suggest you should use some counter variable and use activity method onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState()  to store and retrieve. If you don't want to reset the counter when app got killed, use data persist like SharePreference to store counter.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you have gone through the activity life cycle if not then visit 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

```
boolean secondUse=false;//this should be a field in the activity class
```

onRestart() method is called only when we visited the activity and and came back and then we visit(i.e. when the activity already in the activity stack).

if you have other use case, then using sharedPreference would be better.

override the onRestart() 
inside it write the following

```
if(!seconduse){
//do your stuff
secondUse=true;
}
```

as you said in the edit you need the stuff to work on every visit after first visit then simply put your code in onRestart() method

```
public void onRestart(){
super.onRestart();

RunningStatus = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("RunningStatus", false);
   if (isS1Pressed) {
    if (isPressed) {
        if (RunningStatus = false) {
            pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);
        }
    }
   }
}
```